# How can a make the camera follow a rolling ball from behind?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using unity 2018.3.5f1 so a few solutions to this problem don't work.

Starting from the Roll-A-Ball demo project, I want to extend the camera script to follow the player, but also keeping track of the direction of movement. Ex: If the ball starts moving to the side, I need the camera to rotate around the player's axis to position behind him, and then start following him.

I have tried making the camera a child to the ball i'm trying to control and i've tried making a script but it won't follow the ball correctly it keeps rotating the camera as well as the ball (i'm using this bit of code and trying to modify it as it's the only one that works)

here is the code I have at the moment:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CompleteCameraController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject player;        //Public variable to store a reference to the player game object


    private Vector3 offset;            //Private variable to store the offset distance between the player and camera

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //Calculate and store the offset value by getting the distance between the player's position and camera's position.
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    // LateUpdate is called after Update each frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Set the position of the camera's transform to be the same as the player's, but offset by the calculated offset distance.
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }                                                                         
}
```

I understand why it is rotating but no reasearch is helping me find out how to lock the camera so it is looking behind the ball at all times

Comment: That looks pretty close to me.  The camera is rotating you say?

Comment: yeah the camera rotates around the ball as the ball moves but i'm trying to make the camera follow it and stay behind it without rotating

Comment: Are you sure the camera isn't a child of the player?

Comment: i'm sure the camera isn't the child of the player

Comment: @KurtisGibson you have to make sure that the camera rotation should change with rotation of ball (especially Y axis) . As you have mentioned that when the ball rotates towards left or right, the camera should be behind the ball facing the same angle as it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same camera angle that the camera should follow while following the ball (similar to Temple Run), then try the below code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class CompleteCameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;
    public float distanceFromObject = 3f;
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 lookOnObject = Player.position - transform.position;
        lookOnObject = Player.position - transform.position;
        transform.forward = lookOnObject.normalized;
        Vector3 playerLastPosition;
        playerLastPosition = Player.position - lookOnObject.normalized * distanceFromObject;
        playerLastPosition.y = Player.position.y + distanceFromObject / 2;
        transform.position = playerLastPosition;
    }
```

When the ball moves left or right, the camera will follow the same angle as the ball moves towards.

Comment: monobehavior and transform aren't reconized

Comment: @KurtisGibson add ```using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;```

Comment: ok so it works but it spins like crazy and does nothing when  the camera isn't a child and still spins everywhere

Comment: It spins because it follows the ball right? Try with a cube and make the camera follow the cube. You move the cube manually and see if the camera shakes too much. If it does, then use Lerp function with speed at the last line of code. This will ease the camera movement.

Comment: I want to extend the camera script to follow the player, but also keep track of the direction of movement. like if the ball starts moving to the side, I need the camera to rotate around the player's axis to position behind him, and then start following him. But not rotate the camera on the z or x axis so if i hit right and it rolls to the right i want the camera looking where the ball is going (sorry for the massive paragraph i'm just really struggling to explain what i'm asking)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding some restraints to your camera? If it is only supposed to turn to follow the ball, you can freeze the position of 2 axes (x and z), and only let the camera rotate around the y axis of the ball.

You can play around with the restraints on the Inspector, or use `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX;` in the camera script.

(EDIT) Sorry, this is how you would do it if the gameObject has a rigidbody, but the idea is the same if it doesn't have one.

When you're setting the position or rotation of the camera, think about which components of the position/rotation you actually want to change (x,y,z).
Use `offset = new Vector3 (offset.x, offset.y, offset.z)`and replace anything that shouldn't change with a constant.

Also, when you made the Camera the child of the ball, you could have set it so that every frame, the Camera updates in such a way that it won't roll with the ball. You could do this by putting code in the update method of the camera that sets the component x, y, or z equal to some constant. Whatever axis the ground plane is on is probably the correct choice.

Comment: the camera doesn't rotate and i have no idea how to put restraints on to a camera

Comment: I still have no idea what you are talking about i have no idea what i'm doing i make it by messing about with the defult stuff

Comment: so it follows it but only looks at it from one angle i want it to look at the ball from behind the ball as it moves towards stuff but ass its a ball i can't use the normal follow script becease making it a child of the ball makes it rotate around the ball as the ball rotates